# Uppercase pagenumbering (roman) using \frontmatter

Tags: memoir, page-numbering, front-matter, roman-numerals

I am using `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` so my pagenumbering is correct. However, i would like my roman pagenumbering in `\frontmatter` to be uppercase. Is there any easy way to do so?

ps: i am using a adapted `memoir` as class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know much about memoir, but adding `\pagenumbering{Roman}` immediately after `\frontmatter` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Since it might not be obvious to everyone (at least, I was a bit suprised): `\pagenumbering{roman}` gives us lowercase roman numerals, while `\pagenumbering{Roman}` gives us the desired uppercase numerals. So, the capitalization of the argument is important here.

Answer (score 7):

The page numbering scheme used in the front matter is in the command `\@memfront`, so

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@memfront}{%
  \@smemfront\pagenumbering{Roman}}
\makeatother
```

would be the "official" way, but I agree that Torbjorn's method is slicker.