# pagenumbering{Roman} doesn't work

Tags: page-numbering, roman-numerals

I have a document I want to number in uppercase-Roman letters only. If I add `\pagenumbering{Roman}` to the document, I get the error message

```
 "Missing number, treated as zero",
```

and the page numbering is omitted. I've tried different pagestyles, but I have the same problem for all of them. I've also followed [Uppercase pagenumbering (roman) using \frontmatter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20462), but that also didn't solve my problem. My minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Latin}

\setcounter{page}{1}

  Text!

\end{document}
```

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). `:)`

Comment: `Roman` is ok, but there's no `Latin` numbering by default - perhaps you mean `Alph`.

Comment: Using `\pagenumbering{Roman}` instead of `\pagenumbering{Latin}` works for me.

Comment: @john_leo `pagenumbering{Roman}` works with no problem. You have `\pagenumbering{Latin}` in your example.

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry, I just noticed. Sorry for the silly question.